# Orange3-spark addon installed but no widgets inside

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, orange

I want to install the Orange3-spark addon,
I checked the requirements and it was (Apache Spark, Pandas, and orange3),

## **Problem Description**

I installed it according to the order below, added the spark addon (GUI approach), no error messages, but there were no widgets shown in the Spark ML section.. The Spark ML section is empty,

## Installation Steps

Installed Apache Spark 2.1.1 with Hadoop 2.7 on a Windows 10 machine.
Scala 2.11.8 (comes with Spark)
Checked Spark using (spark-shell) in command prompt
Installed Anaconda 4.4.0 Python 3.6 version
Verified that Pandas is installed within Anaconda
Installed Orange version 3.4.4

## Installed Spark Addon (GUI way from orange)

Can you please instruct me on what to do ?

I have never used Python before, I know the job of most of the above-mentioned components, however, this is the first time that I install any of the above. So please bear with me and be clear with your comments ;))

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the network add on in Orange3 and overcame it by doing a terminal install with root access via sudo instead of the canvas gui install. Try a command line install running as administrator via runas.